# Naive 2D Square Matrix Multiplication using pyopencl

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I'm trying to implement a simple naive MVM kernel for two square matrices using OpenCL and the *pyopencl* python library, however, the result is not as expected. My OpenCL and Python code used are as follows:

The naive OpenCL kernel:

```
__kernel void MM(const int M,
        const int N,
        const int K,
        const __global float* A,
        const __global float* B,
        __global float* C) {

    const int row = get_global_id(0); // Row ID of C (0..M)
    const int col = get_global_id(1); // Column ID of C (0...N)
    float acc = 0.0f;
    for (int i=0; i < K; i++) {
        acc += A[i*M + row] * B[col*K + i];
    }
    C[col*M + row] = acc;
}
```

The corresponding python script:

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl


ctx - cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
mf = cl.mem_flags
kernelsource = open('MM.cl').read()
program = cl.Program(ctx, kernelsource).build()
dim = 25
a = np.random.rand(dim, dim).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(dim, dim).astype(np.float32)
a_cl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a.flatten())
b_cl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b.flatten())

result = np.zeros(shape=dim*dim).astype(np.float32)
result_cl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, result.nbytes)

program.MM(queue, (dim, dim), None, np.int32(dim), np.int32(dim), np.int32(dim), a_cl, b_cl, result_cl)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, result_cl)

print(result.reshape(dim, dim))
print(np.matmul(a, b))
```

Comment: What are the expected results? How do you check them?

Comment: printing result.reshape(dim, dim) and np.matmul(a, b) in the python script. Assuming the kernel and associated pyopencl code is functionally correct, they should generate the same result as np.matmul.